# Замена FragmentA на FragmentB

Tags: java, android

Есть `BottomNavigationView` в котором есть `OneFragment`.

В `OneFragment` Есть кнопка, при нажатии на которые должен открываться `TwoFragment` (`TwoFragment` не состоит в `BottomNavigationView`). Но при этом чтобы `BottomNavigationView`всегда отображалась. При нажатии на кнопку назад должен снова открываться `OneFragment` Подскажите как это реализовать, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам понадобятся 3 фрагмента:

1. Первый будет просто контейнером для второго и третьего. При старте будет отображать внутри себя второй фрагмент. Также будет иметь метод для замены первого фрагмента на второй. Также должен уметь обрабатывать нажатие на кнопку назад, чтобы откатить транзакцию отображенния второго фрагмента.
2. Второй фрагмент - это тот, что у вас сейчас через BottomNavigationView отображается.
3. Третий - тот, что вам надо поверх/вместо второго отобразить.

Для первого фрагмента важно использовать `childFragmentManager`, вместо `fragmentManager` для отображения первого и второго фрагментов.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо @ЮрийСПб за ответ, вот что мне удалось найти, возможно кому-то пригодится.

Документация: [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

```
MyFragmentB fragmentB = new MyFragmentB();
```

Чтобы заменить фрагмент:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragmentB)
                    .addToBackStack(MyFragmentA.class.getSimpleName())
                    .commit();
```

Чтобы добавить фрагмент:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, fragmentB)
                    .addToBackStack(MyFragmentA.class.getSimpleName())
                    .commit();
```

Чтобы передать пакет во фрагмент (от действия к фрагменту ИЛИ от фрагмента к фрагменту):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("String", "String text");
bundle.putInt("Integer", Integer value);
bundle.putDouble("Double", Double value);
bundle.putBoolean("Boolean", Boolean value);

...
fragmentB.setArguments(bundle);
```

Чтобы получить пакет во фрагменте:

```
getArguments().getString("String");//String text
getArguments().getInt("Integer");//Integer value
getArguments().getDouble("Double");//Double value
getArguments().getBoolean("Boolean");//Boolean value
```